# How to Create 3(country,state and city) dropdowns that populates data with each other in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to create 3 dropdowns such as country,state,city.Based on selection in country option it should populate the state and based on country and state selected option the city dropdown should populate itself in react js. Thanks in Advance

**i want add more states here in the usa country**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      countries: [
        {
          name: "Germany",
          states: [
            {
              name: "A",
              cities: ["Duesseldorf", "Leinfelden-Echterdingen", "Eschborn"]
            }
          ]
        },
        { name: "Spain", states: [{ name: "B", cities: ["Barcelona"] }] },

        { name: "USA", states: [{ name: "C", cities: ["Downers Grove"] }] },
        {
          name: "Mexico",
          states: [{ name: ["D", "F", "H"], cities: ["Puebla"] }]
        },
        {
          name: "India",
          states: [
            { name: "E", cities: ["Delhi", "Kolkata", "Mumbai", "Bangalore"] }
          ]
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  changeCountry(event) {
    this.setState({ selectedCountry: event.target.value });
    this.setState({
      states: this.state.countries.find(
        (cntry) => cntry.name === event.target.value
      ).states
    });
  }

  changeState(event) {
    this.setState({ selectedState: event.target.value });
    const stats = this.state.countries.find(
      (cntry) => cntry.name === this.state.selectedCountry
    ).states;
    this.setState({
      cities: stats.find((stat) => stat.name === event.target.value).cities
    });
  }
```

i want  to display more states and city in one country (3 dropdowns)

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <h2>Cascading or Dependent Dropdown using React</h2>

        <div>
          <label>Country</label>
          <select
            placeholder="Country"
            value={this.state.selectedCountry}
            onChange={this.changeCountry}
          >
            <option>--Choose Country--</option>
            {this.state.countries.map((e, key) => {
              return <option key={key}>{e.name}</option>;
            })}
          </select>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>State</label>
          <select
            placeholder="State"
            value={this.state.selectedState}
            onChange={this.changeState}
          >
            <option>--Choose State--</option>
            {this.state.states.map((e, key) => {
              return <option key={key}>{e.name}</option>;
            })}
          </select>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>City</label>
          <select placeholder="City">
            <option>--Choose City--</option>
            {this.state.cities.map((e, key) => {
              return <option key={key}>{e}</option>;
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is in a good direction. Though you can simplify it. Here's an example on how you can do it using React Hooks.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-monad-kzp3p?file=/src/App.js

We start off by creation 3 states:

```
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = React.useState();
  const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = React.useState();
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = React.useState();

  const availableState = data.countries.find((c) => c.name === selectedCountry);
  const availableCities = availableState?.states?.find(
    (s) => s.name === selectedState
  );
```

Normally their values will be `undefined`. Every time you make a selection in the dropdown, we can update them. When updated, we can use the `data` to find the corresponding `states` (in `availableState`). And if a state has been selected, we can use that property to find the `cities` for this state.

The `?.states` is a null check. So if the `availableState` has not been set yet, we won't try to call any functions on it.

This way we can use the same properties for both rendering and finding the correct data. Removing a lot of update complexity.

The render would look like this:

```
return (
    <div id="container">
      <h2>Cascading or Dependent Dropdown using React</h2>

      <div>
        <label>Country</label>
        <select
          placeholder="Country"
          value={selectedCountry}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedCountry(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option>--Choose Country--</option>
          {data.countries.map((value, key) => {
            return (
              <option value={value.name} key={key}>
                {value.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>State</label>
        <select
          placeholder="State"
          value={selectedState}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedState(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option>--Choose State--</option>
          {availableState?.states.map((e, key) => {
            return (
              <option value={e.name} key={key}>
                {e.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>City</label>
        <select
          placeholder="City"
          value={selectedCity}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedCity(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option>--Choose City--</option>
          {availableCities?.cities.map((e, key) => {
            return (
              <option value={e.name} key={key}>
                {e}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Unexpected token    const availableState = data.countries.find((c) => c.name === 
                                   selectedCountry);
  const availableCities = availableState?.states?.find(
                                             ^
    (s) => s.name === selectedState
     );

Answer (score 0):

In user registration, we use the list of countries, states and cities & automatically fetch the data if the user selects the field.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Country, State, City } from 'country-state-city';
import axios from 'axios';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';


const Index= (props) => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [states, setStates] = useState([]);
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState('');
  const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState('');
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCountries = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const result = await Country.getAllCountries();
        let allCountries = [];
        allCountries = result?.map(({ isoCode, name }) => ({
          isoCode,
          name
        }));
        const [{ isoCode: firstCountry } = {}] = allCountries;
        setCountries(allCountries);
        setSelectedCountry(firstCountry);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setCountries([]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    getCountries();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getStates = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await State.getStatesOfCountry(selectedCountry);
        let allStates = [];
        allStates = result?.map(({ isoCode, name }) => ({
          isoCode,
          name
        }));
        const [{ isoCode: firstState = '' } = {}] = allStates;
        setCities([]);
        setSelectedCity('');
        setStates(allStates);
        setSelectedState(firstState);
      } catch (error) {
        setStates([]);
        setCities([]);
        setSelectedCity('');
      }
    };

    getStates();
  }, [selectedCountry]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCities = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await City.getCitiesOfState(
          selectedCountry,
          selectedState
        );
        let allCities = [];
        allCities = result?.map(({ name }) => ({
          name
        }));
        const [{ name: firstCity = '' } = {}] = allCities;
        setCities(allCities);
        setSelectedCity(firstCity);
      } catch (error) {
        setCities([]);
      }
    };

    getCities();
  }, [selectedState]);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const { user } = props;
      const updatedData = {
        country: countries.find(
          (country) => country.isoCode === selectedCountry
        )?.name,
        state:
          states.find((state) => state.isoCode === selectedState)?.name || '', // or condition added because selectedState might come as undefined
        city: selectedCity
      };

      await axios.post(`/register`, {
        ...user,
        ...updatedData
      });
      Swal.fire('Awesome!', "You're successfully registered!", 'success').then(
        (result) => {
          if (result.isConfirmed || result.isDismissed) {
            props.resetUser();
            props.history.push('/');
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: error.response.data
        });
        console.log('error', error.response.data);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form className="input-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <motion.div
        className="col-md-6 offset-md-3"
        initial={{ x: '-100vw' }}
        animate={{ x: 0 }}
        transition={{ stiffness: 150 }}
      >
        <Form.Group controlId="country">
          {isLoading && (
            <p className="loading">Loading countries. Please wait...</p>
          )}
          <Form.Label>Country</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            as="select"
            name="country"
            value={selectedCountry}
            onChange={(event) => setSelectedCountry(event.target.value)}
          >
            {countries.map(({ isoCode, name }) => (
              <option value={isoCode} key={isoCode}>
                {name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="state">
          <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            as="select"
            name="state"
            value={selectedState}
            onChange={(event) => setSelectedState(event.target.value)}
          >
            {states.length > 0 ? (
              states.map(({ isoCode, name }) => (
                <option value={isoCode} key={isoCode}>
                  {name}
                </option>
              ))
            ) : (
              <option value="" key="">
                No state found
              </option>
            )}
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="city">
          <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            as="select"
            name="city"
            value={selectedCity}
            onChange={(event) => setSelectedCity(event.target.value)}
          >
            {cities.length > 0 ? (
              cities.map(({ name }) => (
                <option value={name} key={name}>
                  {name}
                </option>
              ))
            ) : (
              <option value="">No cities found</option>
            )}
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Register
        </Button>
      </motion.div>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default Index;
```